# How do I print the value present in memory address in java?

Tags: java, string, memory, memory-address

I created a new String Object using new keyword. And printed its memory address as below. Then I assigned that object to point to another new object.

```
    String s2 = new String("school");
    System.out.println("hash address of s2 \"school\" : " + System.identityHashCode(s2));


    s2 = new String("hmmmm....");
    System.out.println("hash address of s2 \"hmmm....\" : " + System.identityHashCode(s2));
```

My output is as below:

```
hash address of s2 "school" : 5592464
hash address of s2 "hmmm...." : 1830712962
```

Now I am curious to see what value is present in the memory address 5592464, or if it is already garbage collected, as no one is pointing to this memory location at the moment and it seems like it is eligible for garbage collection.

What is the java code to get the value present in any memory location?
As per my code instance above, is there a way where I can ask JVM to give me any values if presented in the above memory address 5592464?

Comment: The hashCode -- even the 'system' (=java.lang.Object) hashCode -- is **not an address** and never was, although I think some of the pre-release prototypes 30+ years ago _might_ have done so. Yes the first String, the only reference to which you destroyed, is _eligible_ for GC, but the chance it has actually been GC'ed one statement later is tiny, maybe one in a billion. Even if it is, that doesn't mean the data formerly in it is changed; that might not happen until the space is re-allocated for a new object. And if/when your code is JITted the object(s) might be elided entirely.

Answer (score 3):

> And printed its memory address as below.

`System.identityHashCode` does not return a memory address. By trivial proof: It returns an `int`, and computers exist with more than 4GB of memory (an `int` can only address at most 4GB worth of memory), Q.E.D.

It returns some number that is not 'stable' under JVM reboots that is likely, but not guaranteed to, be distinct from what `System.identityHashCode` would return for any other object, and is guaranteed to be identical to any other calls to iHC passing a reference to the same object.

> Now I am curious to see what value is present in the memory address 5592464

Impossible. For starters, 5592464 is not a memory address. Even if it somehow was, java is [A] managed, and [B] strictly so, meaning: You cannot write code that just looks at some memory address. If you try to construct byte code that does so anyway, the class loader will notice and reject the class file (the loader throws a `VerifyError`).

The reason java calls it a 'reference' instead of the more common term 'pointer', is explicitly because the term 'pointer' also tends to carry the baggage of 'pointer math': A C pointer? You can add 5 to it and then ask what's there. Java references aren't like that. It is not possible to 'add 4' to a pointer (reference) in java, nor is it possible to just go ahead and ask what's there.

> s per my code instance above, is there a way where I can ask JVM to give me any values if presented in the above memory address 5592464?

So, no.

The one place where stuff like this can be done, is `com.sun.misc.Unsafe` which is a class that loses functionality with every new java release, is hard to use, and doesn't work like the javadoc might suggest. Its very name (`com.sun` is more or less defined as stuff you shouldn't touch and which may change at any time) suggests this. I include it here to be complete, but you definitely don't want to use it here:

- If you want to write java code that e.g. "checks if something has been garbage collected yet", this isn't the way. Java has reference queues to observe the garbage collection process.
- If you want to write java code that attempts to manipulate memory directly, Unsafe probably isn't going to actually give you want you want, and you just plain don't want to do that sort of thing. Whatever problem you have where you went: "I know! I'll just fiddle with memory and that will be how I solve the problem!" - that's not the right solution; I'm sure there's a better one.
- If you want to observe raw memory to learn how the JVM works, or to debug JVM issues, then [A] that's not useful to learn about, as a JVM implementation is free to do whatever it wants - whatever you learn from this would only apply to the specific JVM impl and version you are using, and in many cases, only on that exact OS, and [B] this is a poor take on the idea of monitoring main memory to learn / observe / bugfix. You should be using a C-level debugger for this, such as gdb. It's also rocket science: You need to have a ton of experience, there are few tutorials, everything depends on version, you need to build and install the JVM sources, get a whole boatload of tool chains, and be an expert at all of them.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. One more doubt I have here is, when we create the String object with new keyword, and make that reference variable point to another String object, for ex: `String a = new String ("happy"); a = new String("sad"); ` At this point the string "happy" will be assigned for GC or not? Since we say Strings are immutable, will GC be able to delete this headless string object in heap?
If it is garbage collected then what will happen to its interned copy present in String constant pool? will it be garbaged collected from here too?

Comment: _At this point the string "happy" will be assigned for GC or not?_ Again you're making assumptions you cannot make. Objects do not get actively assigned. The JVM spec doesn't make any statement about the _how_. For example, in modern GC impls, it's reversed: new objects are allocated on a page. Every so often the _active_ objects are copied to a different page and the page is reused. Nothing is 'wiped' - it's just overwritten. This is called generational garbage collection.

Comment: You're asking all sorts of questions about the GC process, and I'm not sure why. [A] If you feel like the JVM is not clearing out memory that it should, you're most likely wrong. Show the code and the situation where you feel this is going wrong. [B] If you're just intrigued: It's _incredibly_ complex, go spend a month reading docs, sources, etc first. You're doing the equivalent of asking on a nasa engineer SO: "Hey, so, uh.. moon landers, what abbouttem?" [C] you want to write java code that interacts with GC status: Check `java.lang.ref` package, it's the only reasonable way.

Comment: But, to answer the questions in your comment: `new String("happy")` means there are now 2 objects in the heap with value "happy" - the one loaded by the classloader, and the one you just made (`new` means you get a new object, period. Even if it's kinda useless). The 'new one' will be GCed eventually. The classloadered one never will. This isn't an issue unless you make it a habit of sticking string literals in your java source files with millions of characters in em. Don't do that.